# MySql InnoDB Repeatable Read Unexpected behavior of locks

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, snapshot, database-deadlocks

As I know, innoDB use mechanism of consistent **non blocking** read, 
so every transaction works with its own snapshot.

it is told also in official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)

> **A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.**

But I unexpectedly faced with behavior when classic 'read/update' deadlock appears:

1. *Isolation level* *REPEATABLE READ* (also is reproduced with *READ COMMITTED*)
2. *Transaction 1* reads row (**NOT** *lock in share mode*).
3. *Transaction 2* reads the same row ( **ALSO NOT** *lock in share mode*).
   then
4. *Transaction 1* tries to update this row.
5. *Transaction 2* also tries to update this row.

After last step, innoDB detects deadlock (there is LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK below):
    ----------------
    2017-03-31 16:07:03 0x1f58
    *** (1) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 413412, ACTIVE 20 sec starting index read
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
    MySQL thread id 33, OS thread handle 8148, query id 102005 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating

```
/* update Order */ update `Order` set ... <fields to update>

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2151 page no 709 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `ooapp2`.`order` trx id 413412 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 54; compact format; info bits 0

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 413413, ACTIVE 11 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 28, OS thread handle 8024, query id 102008 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating

/* update Order */ update `Order` set ...<fields to update>

*** (2) **HOLDS THE LOCK(S):**
RECORD LOCKS space id 2151 page no 709 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `ooapp2`.`order` trx id 413413 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 54; compact format; info bits 0

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2151 page no 709 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `ooapp2`.`order` trx id 413413 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 54; compact format; info bits 0

 *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I can't understand, what happens, why Transaction 2

> HOLDS THE LOCK(S)

so if innoDB nevertheless not use Consistent Read with snapshot and sets S-locks
this does not correspond to the fact that is written in official manual.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.  If you might be updating a row, but meanwhile need the value, use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;`.  Just do that, and forget about `tx_isolation`.  Normally, this will turn a Deadlock into a delay.  (See `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to an over-generous 50 seconds.)

Also, when you *do* get a Deadlock, re-run the entire transaction.  Deadlocks will happen no matter how hard you try to avoid them.